# C# byte[] to long and back

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to convert a given byte array to an int. Then I want to reverse the process. That is I want to get back the original byte array from that int.
I thought something like this would have worked:

```
byte[] myBytes = { 0, 0, 0, 32 };
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse(myBytes);
int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(myBytes, 0);
Console.WriteLine("int: {0}", i); // Output: 32

byte[] newBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
Console.WriteLine("byte array: " + BitConverter.ToString(newBytes));
// Outputs: 20-00-00-00
```

So it doesn't give me back the original byte array. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You're reversing the bytes with `Array.Reverse` for no obvious reason - given that you're using `BitConverter` for both conversion *to* an `int` and *from* an `int`, you don't need the `Array.Reverse` call at all.

If you want to treat the byte array as big-endian and you're faced with a little-endian `BitConverter`, you have to reverse the array in *both* cases, not just one. Basically you should regard `BitConverter` as providing a reversible conversion, but it may not be the exact conversion you want.

You might want to use my `EndianBitConverter` in my [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) project if you want to specify endianness for this kind of conversion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I am not interested about endianess at all, and when i remove the Array.reverse it outputs 00-00-00-20. The original array was 00-00-00-32, so I'm still not getting the original one.
Later I will try your EndianBitConverter.

Comment: @Jonathan: No, the original array was effectively `"00-00-00-20"`, because `BitConverter.ToString` formats it in hex, whereas you're using a *decimal* literal in the array initializer. Put `Console.WriteLine("byte array: " + BitConverter.ToString(myBytes));` to start with and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Yes I see now, BitConverter.ToString was confusing me. Thank you for your help!